# firefox addon sdk page-worker blocks main thread

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm crawling about 20 Web sites in the background, when a page loads, within the addon script, with the page-worker. Unfortunately the browser freezes, unpredictable during that time.

I tried to use timers.setTimeout(..., 0-400ms) and also tried the example from the wiki

```
function executeSoon(aFunc) {
    var tm = Cc["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"]
        .getService(Ci.nsIThreadManager);

    tm.mainThread.dispatch({
        run: function () {
            aFunc();
        }
    }, Ci.nsIThread.DISPATCH_NORMAL);
}
```

but this also freezes the UI. Is there any other solution?

The crawling code:

```
...
timer.setTimeout(function () {
    let pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
       contentScriptFile: self.data.url("js/extractor.js"),
           contentURL:        url
    });

    pageWorker.port.on("loaded", function (content) {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(content);
        }
    });
}, 200)
...
```

The extractor.js, even in simpler cases, where it return body.textContent, is blocking.

Comment: What is the crawling code you are trying to run, if you post that we can help you out.

Comment: @Noitidart I added the code, it's nothing special.

Comment: Whats in js/extractor.js? That's the code that locks it up, the code you have there doesn't lock anything.

Answer (score 0):

The page-worker API just creates an invisible page, it does not do so on a background thread since it has to create a complete window/document environment including layout to allow for full dom/styling functionality and layout always happens on the main thread.

If you want to do calculations in the background you should use the Worker or ChromeWorker APIs, in which you won't have access to DOM and many other APIs.

In the SDK you can use

```
const { ChromeWorker } = require("chrome");
```

Comment: Since I'm not able to use for background processing the DOM API anyways, I chose to use net/url's readURI function, to receive the raw HTML. This not ideal, but much faster, of course. Is there somewhere good documentation for the worker/ChromeWorker API being used from the addon script? I can't find anything good yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Firefox uses the main thread for page-workers, in Firefox nightly content pages uses separate processes, which means that page-workers will use a separate processes too, so give [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) a try, it should work there, and this will be released in a few months.

Comment: That would be quiet awesome, thanks for the hint. Is there somewhere a release note, that you can reference?